# Errors related to lack of support java 8 despite Retrolambda

Tags: java, android, retrolambda

I followed this readme https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda

I added
`classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.7.1'` to gradle.build

and

`apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'` to gradle.build (app)

and

```
android {
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

But I'm getting error like:

```
Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)
Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): Landroidx/room/migration/AutoMigrationCallback;onPostMigrate(Landroidx/sqlite/db/SupportSQLiteDatabase;)V
```

Comment: your min api level (Must be >=26)?

Comment: My min api level is 19 and I need it

Comment: Use can refer this link: https://akhilbattula.medium.com/invoke-customs-are-only-supported-starting-with-android-o-min-api-26-solution-68ac4e619ce0